# Can instrument dual given by a non-CFII during PPL training be credited towards the 25 hours of SIM/Actual time required for an instrument rating?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

A person applying for a U.S. airplane instrument rating must have at least **3 hours** of flight training on the control and maneuvering of an airplane solely by reference to instruments. This training can be given by a Certified Flight Instructor Airplane - **CFIA** (without an Instrument Instructor Rating - **CFII**).

To obtain an instrument rating the pilot must have **40** hours of actual or simulated time of which **15** hours must be "dual received" from a **CFII**. The remaining **25** hours of actual or simulated time do **not** have to be "dual received" by a CFIA or CFII (these hours could be with a Safety Pilot, CFIA or CFII).

**SCENARIO:** During the PPL flight training all of which was conducted by a **CFIA**, the pilot received **7** hours of flight training (dual received) on the control and maneuvering of an airplane solely by reference to instruments (which is 4 hours more than the minimum required 3 hours). **None** of this "dual received" time, since given by a **CFIA**, can be credited towards the **15** hours of flight training required to be given by a **CFII** for an instrument rating.

**QUESTION:** Can the **entire 7 hours** (not just the **3 hours** minimum required for the PPL) of flight training (**dual received and logged** as given by a **CFIA**) on the control and maneuvering of an airplane solely by reference to instruments during the pilot's PPL  training be **credited** towards the **25** hours of actual or simulated instrument time required by FAR61.65 (d)(2) [*reference shown below*]? (Again, not part of the required **15 hours** that must be given by a **CFII**)

---

**REFERENCE**

**Training for PPL** (pertinent portion of the U.S. FAR regulation)

> **61.109 Aeronautical experience.**

> > **3 hours of flight training in a single-engine airplane on the control and maneuvering of an airplane solely by reference to instruments**, including straight and level flight, constant airspeed climbs and descents, turns to a heading, recovery from unusual flight attitudes, radio communications, and the use of navigation systems/facilities and radar services appropriate to instrument flight; (emphasis is mine)

**Training for Instrument Rating** (pertinent portion of the U.S.FAR regulation)

> **61.65 – Instrument rating requirements.**

> > (d) (2) **Forty hours of actual or simulated instrument time** in the areas of operation listed in paragraph (c) of this section, of which **15 hours must have been received from an authorized instructor who holds an instrument-airplane rating**, and the instrument time includes:(emphasis is mine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Rohlfing (2016) interpretation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/interpretations/Data/interps/2016/Rohlfing_2016_Legal_Interpretation.pdf) you can indeed count the private time in the way you described:

> Therefore, the 3 hours of flight training on "the control and
> maneuvering of an airplane solely by reference to instruments" in
> § 61.109(a)(3) may be applied toward the 40  hours of actual or simulated instrument time under § 61.65(d)(2), but may not be applied
> toward the 15 hours of instrument training unless the flight
> instructor who provided the flight training under § 61.109(a)(3) held
> an instrument rating on his or her flight instructor  certificate and
> otherwise meets the requirements of § 61.65.

Comment: I'm familiar with this interpretation, but what about the full 7 hours of time (per my question) during PPL training (not the minimum required 3 hours) being similarly credited towards the 25 hours of non-CFII time for an instrument rating?

Comment: I don't immediately see a reason why the additional 4 hours couldn't be counted in the same way, unless you found something in your research? 61.109 says "at least" 3 hours, meaning it's a minimum and not a fixed amount of time.

Comment: I think the full 7 hours can be credited (towards the 25 hours in question [not the 15 required to be given by a CFII]). This would mean that a CFIA gave and logged dual instruction to an instrument pilot-in-training.  In past ASE similar questions not everyone has agreed with this position.  So I'm hoping someone can find a clarifying and definitive answer.

Comment: @ymb1 I agree. I'm looking for answer that addresses the 7 hours specifically. I do believe the 7 hours would count though based on the general wording of the Rohlfing interpretation.

Comment: @757toga: I understand, but the fact remains, for a definitive answer to the 7 hours specifically, we need another legal case. Or, Law.SE can help with the legal wording of both the regs and Rohlfing assuming they're open to interpretation.